# Tensorflow: Unexpected EOF while parsing using CPU tf.device

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm kinda new in Python and using Tensorflow, but now I'm just trying to implement basic Word2Vec tutorial from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/code/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py).

It has code like this:

```
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    embeddings = tf.Variable(
        tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)
```

When I run the `with tf.device` part it outputs this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-26-83a85a16701d>", line 1

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

    SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

And when I run the whole block, it outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "<ipython-input-23-79908ea0756f>", line 5, in <module>
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)

 File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\embedding_ops.py", line 100, in embedding_lookup
    with ops.name_scope(name, "embedding_lookup", params + [ids]) as name:

  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 59, in `__enter__`
    return next(self.gen)


 File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4055, in name_scope
    g = _get_graph_from_inputs(values)


  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3804, in _get_graph_from_inputs
    _assert_same_graph(original_graph_element, graph_element)


 File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3743, in _assert_same_graph
    "%s must be from the same graph as %s." % (item, original_item))


ValueError: Tensor("Placeholder_2:0", shape=(128,), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Variable_6:0", shape=(50000, 128), dtype=float32_ref, device=/device:CPU:0).
```

Thank you before!

Comment: Is your indentation correct? Is that the exact format your code has?

Comment: It's a syntax error in your python, for the first error. You can't run it in isolation. For the second error, you're expecting something that's `128xN`, and feeding `Nx128`. Try transposing the input.